# How to delete files from SVN using SVN kit jar

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I need to delete a file in the svn repository by using **svn kit jar**.

I tried

`SVNFileUtil.deleteFile(new File("URL"));`

It does not throw any error. but am not able to delete the file which i given in url.

my code:

```
       repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));

       //create authentication data
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
           SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(
                   prop.getProperty("SVNusername"), 
                   prop.getProperty("SVNpassword"));
              repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

        //need to identify latest revision
        long latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
        System.out.println("Repository Latest Revision: " + latestRevision);

        //create client manager and set authentication
        SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
        ourClientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        //use SVNUpdateClient to do the export
        SVNCommitClient commitClient = ourClientManager.getCommitClient();
        commitClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
   SVNFileUtil.deleteFile(new File(urln));
       SVNCommitClient client = new SVNCommitClient(authManager, null);

       SVNCommitInfo info;
```

Comment: The question seems not related with Git. Is there any special reason to use "git" tag?

Answer (score 3):

@manuelcr is right, and alternatively you can use high level code:

```
    final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
    try {
        final SvnRemoteDelete remoteDelete = svnOperationFactory.createRemoteDelete();
        remoteDelete.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromURL(fileUrl));
        remoteDelete.setCommitMessage("Delete a file from the repository");
        final SVNCommitInfo commitInfo = remoteDelete.run();
        if (commitInfo != null) {
            final long newRevision = commitInfo.getNewRevision();
            System.out.println("Removed a file, revision " + newRevision + " created");
        }
    } finally {
        svnOperationFactory.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: when i use your code SvnOperationFactory and SvnRemoteDelete is asking to create a class in the package

Comment: am using svn kit 1.8.4 jar

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNRepositoryFactory.java:207) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.DefaultSVNRepositoryPool.createRepository(DefaultSVNRepositoryPool.java:236) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.createRepository(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:105)

Comment: According to the error message, null is passed to SVNRepositoryFactory.create as SVN URL. Is your fileUrl null in the example?

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko In above how do we pass in the credentials to be used for Authentication at the SVN?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a CommitEditor?

In [this link](http://svnkit.com/kb/dev-guide-commit-operation.html) you have a description about how get one from your SVNRepository and use it for deleting an entry.

Comment: i tried with commit editor but i got this exception at "editor.deleteEntry(url, latestRevision)" as "Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
 at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:85)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVCommitEditor.deleteEntry(DAVCommitEditor.java:107)
 at svndeletesample.Svndeletesample.main(Svndeletesample.java:200)
Java Result: 1"

Comment: This happens when you use ISVNCommitEditor incorrectly. You should call certain methods in certain order like in the examples.